# Specify rank in ranked search query PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've got a search query witch sorts the results based on how many times the term is used in an article. For example 1 time in the title and 1 time in the content. This one will end higher up in the list than a article with te term only in it's content area.
But I want a little extra, is it possible to add multipliers, for example when the term is used in the title then it counts for 2 instead of one. Look at the code below:

```
<?PHP

//SET THE SEARCH TERM
$term = "Search Term";

$sql = "SELECT *, MATCH(subject, message,reference,textbody) AGAINST('". $term ."') as score FROM pages WHERE MATCH (subject, message,reference,textbody) AGAINST('". $term ."') ORDER BY score DESC";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

//BUILD A LIST OF THE RESULTS
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   // your stuff for showing result
}
?>
```

Could you please help me out?

Comment: Execute individual query for each term like subject, message and make UNION of them. and add score + 1,2,3 what you want !

Comment: How can I make a UNION of them do you have an example for me please?

Answer (score 1):

just add `+1` to it like that

```
$sql = "SELECT *, MATCH(subject, message,reference,textbody) AGAINST('". $term ."')+1 as score 
             FROM pages  ORDER BY score DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's MATCH function does not have a feature for weighting the fields.  You would have to create a separate fulltext index on the field you want to have higher weight, and then calculate the relevance against both fulltext indexes with separate MATCH() expressions.

```
SELECT *, 
  MATCH(subject) AGAINST('". $term ."') * 2 AS score_s /* 2x weight */
  MATCH(subject, message, reference, textbody) AGAINST('". $term ."') AS score
FROM pages 
WHERE 
  MATCH(subject, message, reference, textbody) AGAINST('". $term ."') 
ORDER BY score_s + score DESC
```

MySQL's builtin fulltext search is really not very flexible.  Other specialized tools are often a better choice when you have specific functional requirements:

- **Sphinx Search** supports relevance ranking, and the default ranking when you use extended matching mode is by word frequency, which seems to be what you're asking for.
  http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2010/08/17/how-sphinx-relevance-ranking-works/
- **Apache Solr** supports "boosting" the weight of words matching a given field. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_make_.22superman.22_in_the_title_field_score_higher_than_in_the_subject_field

Those other tools are frequently much faster for searching large datasets, too.  See my presentation [Fulltext Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql) for comparisons.

Comment: Jac Engels : Here's your answer :) +1 @Bill Karwin. I am your FAN, the way you answer MySQL questions is truly awesome :)

Comment: @HardikThaker, Thanks! I'm glad to help people learn about MySQL and be more successful in their projects.